# Any way to reduce bind9 memory footprint?

Tags: memory, vps, bind

I am running my own Authoritative DNS on bind9 for like 5 of my domains with little traffic.
I am running them on 2 separate VPS servers (so every Mb of memory costs me some $x2).

Is there any way to reduce it's memory consumption down from ~45-50Mb? (I would be happy with 10-30Mb)

I know there are lighter DNS server alternatives, but this would require to replace server managing software, so I would prefer to stick with bind.

Suggestions? I've heard bind8 is better on memory consumptoin. Will I fall to hell for using it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can take a look into options like:

- datasize [bytes]
- max-cache-size [bytes]
- tcp-clients [number]
- recursive-clients [number]

These are all global options that may actually cause your server to stop responding once hitting the caps, but will limit the memory used.

For a real world example, with a setting of "max-cache-size 1M" my BIND install is using just about 30-35MB of memory (uptime 2 weeks, authoritative for 9 zones, light traffic).

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking. Looks like no drastical changes should be expected with bind9, but still might make a difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not answer you are looking for, but why not go with a hosted DNS? I guess I am not a true geek sysadmin but I offloaded admin stuff that was not so useful for us (email, dns) to dedicated companies instead of wasting my time on it.  We use [www.dnsmadeeasy.com](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com) and they have been great.  The prices are really cheap for a few domains.  It will be cheaper than your VPS, that's for sure.

Comment: Well, they would need me to pay like 60$/year(for primary+secondary) to manage my 5 domains, and I will need to pay more if I would need more than 10.

Also, I want to stick to servers in Russia(due to ping and availability), and we have less choose here in terms of pricing.

Well, I offloaded mail to GMail too, so if there were free and reliable "G-DNS" I would go for it.

Comment: Again not the answer your looking for but, most VPS providers provide free DNS services. Does your existing VPS provider not provide DNS services?

Comment: It does, but I do not want to depend on 1 DNS provider.

I want to have primary and slave DNS servers in separate datacenters on different channels and different companies. 

And I already have that, and it's working great and perfect. 

The only problem is that I had to buy 128Mb VPS for that, 64Mb is about twice cheaper but bind9 does not fit nicely in 64Mb with some extra stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard of [NSD(Name Server Daemon)](http://nlnetlabs.nl/projects/nsd/)? It's designed for authoritative Domain Name Server. It has good performance and very low footprint.

Comment: yes, NSD (and not NDS :-) ) it's a very good choice for an authoritative server. (use by lot of tld)

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at [TinyDNS](http://tinydns.org/) also, its another more popular BIND replacement

Answer (score 1):

The tinydns suggestion is your way to go if you want to save memory. BIND caching of zones is as aggressive as it is pointless, performance-wise a well-designed binary database is just as fast.

Regarding going for DNS hosting, there are several services out there that give it to you for free, for example [Afraid](http://afraid.org/), [BuddyNS](http://www.buddyns.com) and [Hurricane Electric](http://dns.he.net).